# How to downgrade maven version from 3.XX to 2.2.1?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have trouble building a project that needs maven 2.2.1 to get built.
How do I downgrade maven version?

EDIT: more info

I am trying to build the project from the command line. I am building this locally.
I have 3.0.4 version currently installed.

Comment: Download and use the 2.2.1 distribution. Fix all errors 2.2.1 reports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have multiple versions of Maven installed.  You haven't provided a lot of other necessary info - such as do you mean in your build environment or on your local machine.

If your local machine, which I am assuming, do you mean from within eclipse (or another IDE) or from the command line.  From the command line, I am pretty sure all you need to do is redefine MAVEN_HOME.  From eclipse, you can go to Preferences->Maven->Installations.  Click the Add button and put in your 2.2.1 install, then click it as the default and try building that way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem which might occur are in the area of reporting. Other things should work without any problem.